# How to find Strikethrough words in a ppt slide

Tags: office-interop, powerpoint-2010

Is there any way to find strikethrough words in a ppt slide using interop, in c#? I am able to find out the format(Bold, Italic,Underlined) of a word but not able to identify strikethrough words.

Answer (score 0):

The .TextRange2.Font.Strikethrough property of the text will be True if the text is formatted as StrikeThrough